# Error 0xC00CE508 while loading package file into an XML document

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, msbi, msn

[image]

I have a corrupted ssis package with this error:

> Error: Error 0xC00CE508 while loading package file
>   "H:\GBPL_NEW\Fact_Dimension_set_entries.caw" into an XML document. An
>   invalid character was found in text content.  Line 1, Column 3.

The caw file is present. Don't know where I am going wrong!!

I am also getting this while executing the package.

Comment: Go to the file. Open it. Line 1, column 3 - there's an invalid character there. If there isn't one that you can see (could happen) save the file as ASCII or UTF-8.

Comment: hi hila DG, the first line is correct and m doing a cache transform,still not able to resolve it.

Comment: Post Lines 1 and 2 please.

Comment: LK       i d ! 0              ÿÿÿÿ                       c o m p a n y _ i d ! 1             ÿÿÿÿ                                     
                                                       this is the format of my caw file.

Comment: <?xml version="1.0"?> <DTS:Executable xmlns:DTS="www.microsoft.com/SqlServer/Dts" this is the xml file of the package i m using.